# display custom data not worrking react js

Tags: reactjs

i a facing some issue with my code i have modules and custom modules coming from api

when i dont have modules my coustom modules is not showing

today 19-03-2022 i have data in coustum which is not getting displayed
[image]

```
setData(
            Object.keys(modules.data || {}).reduce((obj, item) => {
              if (modules.data[item]) {
                obj[item] = {
                  data: {
                    ...modules.data[item],
                  },
                  ...customs[item],
                };
              } else {
                obj[item] = {
                  ...customs[item],
                };
              }

              return obj;
            }, [])
          );
          // }

          if (modules) {
            setColumns(modules.mainModules);
          }
        }
        // }
      });
```

pls check the working full code i cant post entire code here  so i post in codesandbox

the issue here  is when there is no prededied data custom does not get dispalyed

on 19-3-2022 i want s to display like this

Comment: What is the issue? Can you be more specific than "it's not working"? Can you provide more details?

Comment: @DrewReese as u can see in the screenshot there is data in cutum on 19-03-2022 this data is not getting displayed

Comment: data till 14-03-2022 is only getting displayed

Comment: Are you just trying to merge this `modules.data` into the existing `columns` array? Or something with a `customs` object? When I asked if you could be more specific I meant *what* specifically isn't working with the code you shared. What is the expected result?

Comment: @DrewReese my gole is to display the activity "s"  under "custom" colom on date 19-3-2020

Comment: @DrewReese u can see there is a custom colume at the end of the table pls check the codesandbox so u will understand

Comment: I've looked at your CSB, it doesn't make anything clear with regards to what you want the `setData` logic to do. The only thing I can tell is that you are doing some sort of merging of data between `response.data.Predefined` as `modules`, `response.data.Custom` as `customs`, and `modules.data`. This is why I'm asking what you are expecting the result to be. If we understand what/how you need to merge the data we can see where it's going sideways on you.

Comment: i have added a screenshot , that is how i want my "s" to display  i am  also confused with the login of this problem hope u undersand

Comment: the prediffied and customs need to be merged and displayed date wise

Comment: the issue here i think is happening is when there is no prededied data custom does not get dispalyed

Comment: @DrewReese did u understand my issue

Comment: So are you wanting to merge all the data in `customs` with all the data in `modules.data`? `"19-03-2022"` from the `customs` object isn't a key in the `modules.data` object, so it's not merged.

Comment: how can i achive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question/expected behavior correctly, you want to marge all the `modules.data` object data with all the `customs` object data.

First map the `modules.data` object into objects with the old data saved under a `data` property.

```
const data = Object.entries(modules.data || {}).reduce(
  (obj, [date, data]) => ({
    ...obj,
    [date]: { data }
  }),
  {}
);
```

Then reduce the `customs` object into the result of the `data` by date key.

```
const data2 = Object.entries(customs || {}).reduce(
  (obj, [date, data]) => ({
    ...obj,
    [date]: {
      ...obj[date],
      ...data
    }
  }),
  data
);

setData(data2);
```

[image: Edit display-custom-data-not-worrking-react-js]

[image]

Comment: can u make a woeking codesandbox by editing my code

Comment: also make sure its in accenting order

Comment: @jisaks Sure, here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/display-custom-data-not-worrking-react-js-g5eivd) I forked from yours and updated. As for the ordering, the data doesn't appear to be ordered in your sandbox example, what are you wanting to order the data by?

Comment: i data of  19-3-2022 is not showing in ur codesandbox can u pls recheck? i  also want to order it in acceting date wise

Comment: its okee  take ur time

Comment: @jisaks Ok, code is there now. Again, sorry.

Comment: thanku @Drew but could u pls sort  it accoding to date

Comment: i think the latest date i have is 19-3-2022  so it will come on top

Comment: @jisaks It should be trivial to sort the data. In any case though I've updated the sandbox code to sort by date in reverse chronological order.